# How to obtain the length of a file

Tags: arrays, c, file-length

I am trying to run a simple C program that takes a file of random floating point values, automatically identify the length of the file and use the length to perform further computation. However, my compiler either hangs or I get erroneous results. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  FILE *fptr;
  int count = 0; // Line counter (result)
  char ch; // To store a character read from file

  if ((fptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\Evandovich\\Desktop\\White_Noise.txt", "r"))
      == NULL) {
    printf("Error! opening file");
    // Program exits if the file pointer returns NULL.
    exit(1);
  }

  // Extract characters from file and store in character ch
  for (ch = getc(fptr); ch != EOF; ch = getc(fptr)) {
    if (ch == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
      count = count + 1;
  }
  printf("The file has %d lines\n ", count);

  // use the value of "count" to be the length of the array.
  char arrayNum[count];
  char *eptr;
  double result, result1[count];

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    fscanf(fptr, "%s", &arrayNum[i]);

    /* Convert the provided value to a double */
    result = strtod(&arrayNum[i], &eptr);
    result1[i] = pow(result, 2);
    printf("value %f\n", result1[i]);
  }

  fclose(fptr);
  return 0;
}
```

What particularly is the error? Your input is well appreciated.

INPUT file (N.txt) contains

```
0.137726
0.390126
-0.883234
0.006154
-0.170388
-1.651212
0.510328
```

OUTPUT
The file has 7 files

```
value 0.000000
value 0.000000
value 0.000000
value 0.000000
value 0.000000
value 0.000000
value 0.000000
```

Expected
The file has 7 files

```
value 0.018968
value 0.152198
value 0.780102
value 0.000038
value 0.029032
value 2.726501
value 0.260435
```

Comment: Change the type of `ch` to `int`. This is the return type of `getc` and is necessary to correctly detect `EOF`

Comment: Well, this certainly is not correct - ` fscanf(fptr,"%s", &arrayNum[i]);`   Why are you reading as a string then converting to a double?  Just read in as a double to begin with with %f specifier

Comment: Note that `char arrayNum[count];` defines an array of *single characters*, not an array of strings. Not that you need an array of strings, just a plain single character array large enough to hold the largest "word" in your file.

Comment: You are reading from the file after reaching the end. Also use %lf instead of %s. Add rewind(fptr); before the second for loop.

Comment: Really, you don't need the line-count at all, all you need is something like `double value; while (fscanf(fptr, "%lf", &value) == 1) { printf("value %lf\n", value * value); }` Besides the `fopen` and `fclose` calls that's really all you need in your program.

Comment: [Be kind, rewind](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=be%20kind%20rewind): call `rewind(fpr)` after finding line count.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: When the scanned value is in the correct format but not representable in a `double`, the behavior of `scanf` is not defined by the C standard. The behavior of `strtod` is. So it is preferable to use `strtod`, although of course it would be better to limit the size with `%s` and to check the error indications provided by `strtod`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It depends on what kind of error recovery you want. If you need to keep going past erroneous input, reading strings then parsing is appropriate. If you just want to abort when `fscanf()` reports a failure, you can keep it simple.

Comment: @Barmar: `fscanf` is not specified to report a failure when the scanned value is not representable in a `double`. As I wrote, it is not defined by the C standard. Whether you want to reliably abort or reliably have any other behavior in that case, you cannot use `fscanf` for it, because the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It returns the number of successfully scanned values. If the scanned value can't be parsed as a double, won't it return `0`?

Comment: @Barmar: It is not about parsing. There are numerals that are in the correct format for `%lf` but that may be out of the `double` range. The C standard says then the behavior is not defined. (In cases where the `double` format supports infinities, one might hope nothing is out of range, but the standard is not clear about that. And an implementation is allowed not to support infinities.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's stupid :)

Comment: Thank you guys for your wonderful contributions and suggestions. Those inputs really helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least these problems:

**At end of file**

Code fails as it attempts to read the floating point text from the end of the file. [@ErlingHaaland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75036350/how-to-obtain-the-length-of-a-file/75036435#comment132416543_75036350)

After determining line count, add:

```
 rewind(fptr);
```

**Convoluted read**

Read a line with `fgets()`.  Avoid `"%s"` without a width limit - it might overflow.  Use a line buffer that is based on max line length, not line count.  Convert to a `double` by starting at the begining of the line.

```
#define LINE_SIZE 100
char arrayNum[LINE_SIZE];
if (fgets(arrayNum, sizeof arrayNum, fptr) == NULL) {
  break;
}
result = strtod(arrayNum, &eptr);
```

**Check conversion**

```
errno = 0;
result = strtod(arrayNum, &eptr);
if (arrayNum == eptr || errno) {
  break;
}
```

**Too small a type**

`int getc(FILE *)` typically returns 257 different values: `EOF` and [0...`UCHAR_MAX`].  Saving that in a `char` loses information.  Save in an `int`.

**Line count at risk**

May be off by 1 as the last *line* might not have a `'\n'`: [@Adrian McCarthy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75036467/2410359).

Instead count line *beginnings*.

```
size_t count = 0;
int previous = '\n';
int ch;

while ((ch = getc(fptr) != EOF) {
  if (previous == '\n') {
    count++;
  }
  previous = ch;
}
printf("The file has %zu lines.\n ", count);

// Also
rewind(fptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems:

1. `getc` returns the value of the next `char` as an `int` or the special value `EOF`.  Since your variable `ch` is a `char`, the `EOF` value may not be recognizable in which case the line counting loop might never end.
2. <s>You define arrays whose size is determined by a run time variable `count`.  I use C++ regularly, but I have written in C in a very long time.  When I did write in C, the size of arrays had to be determined at compile time.  Perhaps this is a newer feature of C?  I'd check.</s> Make sure you have compiler warnings enabled.
3. `count` might be short one line if the last line of the file doesn't end with '\n'.  On Posix systems, a line is supposed to end with a newline character.  On Windows, it's common for the newline sequence (typically CR+LF) to be treated as a line separator.  Thus files may or may not end with the newline sequence at the end of the last line.
4. `arrayNum` is an array of `count` characters rather than an array of pointers to character strings.

Comment: Variable-length arrays were added in C99; is 23 years ago "new". They became optional in a later version, but all full-featured implementations have them.

Comment: @Barmar:  Thanks.  I learned C in the K&R to ANSI transition and have been almost exclusively C++ since the mid 1990s.  I think I'd heard C had added variable length arrays, but I never knew whether that was standard, and I never used it so it hadn't stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest, most efficient, and safest way to get file size is to ask the operating system via `stat()`:

```
struct stat statbuf;
stat("C:\\Users\\Evandovich\\Desktop\\White_Noise.txt", &statbuf);
statbuf.st_size; /* The file size in bytes */
```